# Prove a dieudonne vector space is a metric space

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

I'm supposed to prove that a dieudonne vector space is a metric space, but I'm stuck on the triangle inequality. I need to show that $d(x,z) \le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ with $d(x,y)=|x-y|= \sqrt{(y-x|y-x)}$ with $x$ $y$ and $z$ being vectors.

Note that $(y-x|y-x)$ means a dot product so $(y-x) \cdot (y-x)$.

The hint I'm given is to use the Schwarz lemma $|(x|y)| \le |x||y|$.
Any suggestions?

[document about dieudonne](https://drive.google.com/a/notredamehs.com/file/d/0B0GxKBNsllF1eDlMLXFXWHZoX2c/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: what is a dieudonne vector space ?

Comment: Seriously, what is a Dieudonne vector space? This question is the only search result in google for that search term.

Comment: can you do it for me please ?

Comment: I forgot I meant to upload a document to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that 
$$
|x+y|^2=(x+y|x+y)=(x|x)+(y|y)+2(x|y)\leq |x|^2+|y|^2+2|x||y|=(|x|+|y|)^2
$$
So $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$ for all $x$ and $y$ so 
$$
d(x,y)=|x-y|=|x-z+z-y|\leq |x-z|+|z-y|=d(x,z)+d(z,y)
$$

Comment: Did you learn what a Dieudonne vector space is?

Comment: No but I see that he want to proof that a Hilbert space is a normed vector space